How to flush kafka-connect s3-sink after time or size
I have the following kafka connect s3-sink
{
    "name": "my-s3-sink",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.s3.S3SinkConnector",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "topics": "my-topic",
        "topics.dir": "my-dir",
        "behavior.on.null.values": "ignore",
        "s3.region": "us-west-1",
        "s3.bucket.name": "by-bucket",
        "s3.part.size": "5242880",
        "aws.access.key.id": "${AWS_ACCESS_KEY}",
        "aws.secret.access.key": "${AWS_SECRET_KEY}",
        "storage.class": "io.confluent.connect.s3.storage.S3Storage",
        "flush.size": "1000",
        "format.class": "io.confluent.connect.s3.format.avro.AvroFormat",
        "schema.compatibility": "NONE",
        "partitioner.class": "io.confluent.connect.storage.partitioner.TimeBasedPartitioner",
        "path.format": "'year'=YYYY/'month'=MM/'day'=dd/'hour'=HH",
        "partition.duration.ms": "30000",
        "rotate.interval.ms": "30000",
        "locale": "en-US",
        "timezone": "UTC"
    }
}

i want the connector to flush the file to s3 every flush.size records or after a certain time has passed and a flush did not occur.
With this configuration - lets say i publish less than 1000 records, then with this configuration - i see that the connect has opened a output stream to my s3 but i never see it flush. not even 30 seconds have passed. im wondering what am i missing here in the configuration.
here are the connect logs
[2024-12-18 23:02:28,553] INFO [my-connector|task-0] [Consumer clientId=connector-consumer-connector-0, groupId=connect-connector] Resetting offset for partition my-topic-0 to position FetchPosition{offset=0, offsetEpoch=Optional.empty, currentLeader=LeaderAndEpoch{leader=Optional[kafka:9092 (id: 1 rack: r1)], epoch=0}}. (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.SubscriptionState:396)
[2024-12-18 23:02:28,556] INFO [my-connector|task-0] Assigned topic partitions: [data-pipeline-policy-report-results-0] (io.confluent.connect.s3.S3SinkTask:159)
[2024-12-18 23:03:18,209] INFO [my-connector|task-0] Opening record writer for: datadir/year=2024/month=12/day=18/hour=23/my-topic+0+0000000000.avro (io.confluent.connect.s3.format.avro.AvroRecordWriterProvider:74)
[2024-12-18 23:03:18,209] INFO [my-connector|task-0] Creating S3 output stream. (io.confluent.connect.s3.storage.S3Storage:200)
[2024-12-18 23:03:18,211] INFO [my-connector|task-0] Create S3OutputStream for bucket 'my-bucket' key 'datadir/year=2024/month=12/day=18/hour=23/my-topic+0+0000000000.avro' (io.confluent.connect.s3.storage.S3OutputStream:101)

and then it hangs.
